# How to create calendar in sketchware?

Tags: calendar, sketchware

I am making an application in sketchware. I want out of a list of 5 people to see in a row who person each sunday is, and to be able to choose from the calendar one sunday day and see which turn is in line. No idea

Any idea for the steps to choose